# No Rotation in image using rotate Animation

Tags: android, animation

Using Rotate Animation in android, but no rotation in image after clicking the button.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView spinImage;
Button buton;

Random r;
int degree =0 , degreeold= 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.spinbutton);
     spinImage= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.spinimage);
     r= new Random();

    buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          degreeold = degree % 360;
        degree = r.nextInt(3600)+720;
           degree= 4400;
            RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation( degreeold, degree,
                    RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF , 0.5f);
            rotate.setDuration(3600);
            rotate.setFillAfter(true);
            rotate.setInterpolator( new DecelerateInterpolator());

            rotate.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });

            spinImage.setAnimation(rotate);
        }
    });
}
```

i am not able to find the mistake why there is no rotation in image. there is no error while running and app open without any delay but there is no animation when clicking the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't started the animation. Try to use `spinImage.startAnimation(rotate);`

setAnimation is meant to give you more fine grained control if you want to start the animation delayed or together with other animations.

From the documentation:

> Sets the next animation to play for this view. If you want the animation to play immediately, use startAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation) instead. This method provides allows fine-grained control over the start time and invalidation, but you must make sure that 1) the animation has a start time set, and 2) the view's parent (which controls animations on its children) will be invalidated when the animation is supposed to start.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `spinImage.setAnimation(rotate);` with `spinImage.startAnimation(rotate);`